# Storing serialized object in database then restoring object state from key

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, this is pretty fun.

Code will illustrate best what I'm thinking about:

```
class Restorable(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def restore(self, serialized_object):
        # I'm aware this is local, just illustrating
        self = pickle.loads(serialized_object)

r = Restorable()
r.a = 1000
r.b = 2000
saved_state = pickle.dumps(r)
r.a = -1
r.b = -1
r.restore(pickle.dumps(saved_state)
# r.a should again be 1000
# r.b should again be 2000
```

The idea is: would be possible to, say, `pickle.dumps()` an object, store it somewhere, modify the real object and later on restore it to its previous state through what I've safely stored?

I've tried the code I've shown above, it does **temporarily** set `self` to the previous state, but only locally - well, no surprise here.

This is a curiosity question.

EDIT: To formulate the question in a clear way:

Is it possible to write an object that would restore its state using a serialized object of the same type?

Actually, I see this can be done by creating an instance of the serialized object inside `restore()` and copying values one by one. But this could be tedious for large objects.

Comment: No. You get a fresh, new object from unpickling.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: +1 to S.Lott - read http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#id3 and think twice why do you need to do this and for what purpose. Since picking will create you new instance is there any reason to add steps which will restore your initial object.

Comment: "This is curiosity question" doesn't make a confusing question suddenly clear.  The idea of a mutable object which is magically restored is very, very confusing.  Rather than claim it's "curiosity", please provide the use case so we can understand the question.

Comment: Well "this is a curiosity question" was supposed to let you know that not everything has a use case. Sometimes it's just "I wonder if this could be done". That's the case here. I liked the concept of somewhat pouring an object into a different one. I asked, hoping to maybe, by some chance, learn about shady area of Python I haven't visited yet.

Comment: @maligree: "not everything has a use case".  That's false.  "somewhat pouring an object into a different one" sounds like a use case.  And a very bad idea.  But it still sounds like a use case.  Please explain what you're trying to make happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in your edit, create a new object (don't assign to `self`, obviously), but instead of copying the attributes one by one you can

```
def restore(self, serialized_object):
    original = pickle.loads(serialized_object)
    self.__dict__.update(original.__dict__)
```

and update all your attributes at once.  Here's your complete (reworked) example:

```
import pickle
class Restorable(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def restore(self, serialized_object):
        original = pickle.loads(serialized_object)
        self.__dict__.update(original.__dict__)

r = Restorable()
r.a = 1000
r.b = 2000
saved_state = pickle.dumps(r)
r.a = -1
r.b = -1
r.restore(saved_state)
print r.a, r.b
```